# ERROR: Job failed: build directory needs to be an absolute path

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

- Installed Gitlab runner on windows
- Registered
- configured a test repo with test gitlab ci yaml configuration file
- CI/CD pipelines shows error

```
ERROR: Job failed: build directory needs to be an absolute path
```

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
image: busybox:latest

before_script:
  - echo "Before script section"
  - echo "For example you might run an update here or install a build dependency"
  - echo "Or perhaps you might print out some debugging details"

after_script:
  - echo "After script section"
  - echo "For example you might do some cleanup here"

build1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Do your build here"

test1:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo "Do a test here"
    - echo "For example run a test suite"

test2:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo "Do another parallel test here"
    - echo "For example run a lint test"

deploy1:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Do your deploy here"
```

Comment: Gitlab runner version ? Check out this issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4251

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what type of runner you have, in my case I had the same issue with docker-ssh runner. A workaround for me was to specify build_dir in config.toml

```
[[runners]]
  name = "jira-ssh-runner"
  executor = "docker-ssh"
  builds_dir = "/home/gitlab-runner/build"
```

Comment: have same error. Works for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On windows it works with double slashes in the path

```
[[runners]]
  name = "development-server-runner"
  url = "https://*****.com"
  token = "n****tq"
  builds_dir = "E:\\00-gitlab-build"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
    enabled = true
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```